# How to Store Access/Refresh Token with AppEngine and Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spotify

I'm building a web app in **AppEngine** that uses the **Spotify** API and I can't figure out the best way to store an access/refresh token locally using Python and AppEngine. I've looked into AppEngine's `Memcache` which just seems like overkill, and Javascript's `localStorage` which just starts to get complicated since I'd have to transfer data back and forth between Python and Javascript constantly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to save the access token from Spotify. I like to use **[Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/)** to save anything shared between my instances, but I not sure that is the best way to do that, but probably it is a simple and fast way. 
So, to solve this issue I'll probably to create an entity in Datastore.

Another alternative could be **[Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)**

Comment: Is that a good way of storing something so temporary though? The refresh token to my knowledge only lasts for an hour before expiring.

Comment: I think so, and probably I'll implement using NDB.  Almost all solution that I created using GAE I had an datastore entity for configuration data like this.